# Nestjs and GraphQL server accessible on Localhost only

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config, nestjs-graphql

I created an api using NestJs and GraphQL, exposing a GraphQL server (Apollo) with a certain port.
Everything works fine as long as I am using `http://localhost:3001/graphql` endpoint. As soon as I change to `http://<ip-address>:3001/graphql` the connection cannot be established.

I modified `main.ts` file to include the host adress as well, and I was expecting to be able to reach the endpoint withing the same machine, but in vain.

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  await app.listen(3001, '0.0.0.0', async () => {
    console.log(` Server started at ${await app.getUrl()}`);
  });
}
bootstrap();
```

Dependencies:

```json
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^10.2.0",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "@nestjs/apollo": "^10.2.0",
```

Comment: Are you able to `ping <ip-address>`?

Comment: Yes I am.
And I also tried to access the Apollo Sandbox from the same machine the server is running in, and I got the same result.
In addition to that I have tested this on 3 different machines (Running the server in the machine and trying to access the Apollo Sandbox on the same machine using the IP)